# Delete rows with locked cells in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet that has formulas that I want to lock once the information in the row is completed, (there is a discharge date). I want the end-user to be able to delete the row and insert it into another worksheet. I do not want to use VBA; I was successful in sequencing the protection steps, but now cannot repeat the process. There has to be a way to use the protect sheet "delete rows" check box and locked cells together to enable this process.

Comment: No, there doesn't *have* to be. Microsoft Excel is an inherently flawed product with many limitations. There are thousands of things that it is *completely impossible* to do with Excel. This is even more true if you are unwilling to use VBA. I do not know of a way to do this without using VBA. You're welcome to keep looking for a way, but I think you will find that the best possible answer is "use VBA, or don't try to do this in the first place".

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with the nature of worksheet protection.  The purpose of locking cells is to prevent users from changing the contents.  If users delete rows, they will be permanently changing the cells, so it makes sense that Excel doesn't allow users to delete rows with locked cells.  What's confusing is that Excel gives you the option to select "delete rows" in the worksheet protection dialog, even though that setting doesn't seem to do anything.  The only complete solution is to use macros to unprotect the sheet, delete/copy the rows, and protect it again.  If you want the cells to be locked for most users, but allow some users to delete rows, another option is to use the "allow users to edit ranges" feature to allow particular users or users with a password to modify cells even though they are locked.  See [How to Sort Locked Cells in Protected Worksheets](http://blog.softartisans.com/2013/10/01/kb-sorting-locked-cells-in-protected-worksheets/) That article is about sorting, but it explains the relevant concepts well.

Answer (score 3):

I agree there should be a way to do this. When you click Protect Sheet, it even asks you "Allow users of this worksheet to"

"Delete Rows" is one of them. So therefore, lock the sheet, allow users to edit unlocked cells, but not other cells, and allow users to delete rows. Should be simple.